# Duplicate in Array not picked up by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

I am working on implementing Front-end guest wishlist.

**Technology:** *HTML, CSS, jQuery, and LocalStorage*

**Process:** Enter the page > Add Product > Add another product > Remove Product

**Issue:** The `if ($.inArray($product_id, wish_list) == -1) {}` doesn't pick the duplicate entries. That means I can add multiple times the same product.

**Steps to re-create:** Add Product  > Validate it has been added to the wishlist > Add the same product second time

**Question:** How do I make the above function picking up that the product has been added and disable the button?

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/y56gerdz/

Comment: Your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *in the question itself* - not in an external resource like JSFiddle. Please edit your question to include the code you're asking about.

Comment: You're checking to see if `$product_id` already exist in  `wish_list`, but the values you actually push into `wish_list` appear to be `$product_str` values, which are totally different from IDs. It's not surprising that no ID is ever a match for your `inArray` check because `wish_list` never holds ID values at all.

Comment: Arghh.. Thanks @apsillers can you add it as answer so I can accept it?